# Some SVG's are not scaling properly in Mobile browser

Tags: html, css, svg

I am having some problems with scaling SVG images on Mobile Browsers for my Website.

While using a Desktop Browser my SVG's scale perfectly. But when I load up my website "top-chatters.com" on Mobile (only tested on Android Chrome), then my header and API SVG's appear to scale terribly.

[Dekstop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQGTJ.png)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRqJt.png)

As you can probably see, the header and API SVG's are not scaling properly.

Here is a link to both of them respectively:

Header: https://top-chatters.com/static/images/header.svg

API: https://top-chatters.com/static/images/api.svg

View source to see the code.

This is how my header is scaled in main.css:

```
#header {
    height: 45px;
}

.header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    max-width: 75%;
}
```

#header is an anchor wrapper, and .header is the actual SVG inserted into the page using img tags:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/header.svg') }}" alt="Header" class="header">
```

My API SVG is templated into the page using the Flask templating system:

```
{% include 'api.svg' %}
```

This is the HTML structure for API:

```
<section id="main-home">
    <div id="main-nav">
        <button type="button" id="intro-btn" class="no-btn-style">Intro</button>
        <div id="nav-splitter"></div>
        <button type="button" id="api-btn" class="no-btn-style">API</button>
    </div>
    {% include 'api.svg' %}
    {% include 'browser.svg' %}
</section>
```

#main-home flex-wrapper CSS:

```
#main-home {
    padding-top: 52px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 52px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

CSS for api.svg (inside SVG defs):

```
<style>
  #api {
    max-height: 85%;
    max-width: 90%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s;
  }
</style>
```

I have tried adding width and height arguments to the API SVG which was suggested in another post. This did nothing. It seems like it is the text that is refusing to scale.

Appreciate you reading this and trying to help me!

EDIT: I have just noticed that the font doesn't appear to be loading in mobile (totally different font), I wonder what is causing this. If I fix that, I will most likely have the solution!

Comment: scale looks fine, but overlapping text. what is the html structure and associated style ?

Comment: I have added additional information about how api is scaled in the updated post :)

Comment: I have just noticed that the font doesn't appear to be loading in mobile (totally different font), I wonder what is causing this. If I fix that, I will most likely have the solution!